# ¿Como puedo convertir un double a long aunque exceda el tipo primitivo long y manejarlo con una excepcion en java 17?

Tags: conversión-de-tipos, java-17

Estoy haciendo un programa que dado un valor entero me diga en que tipos primitivos (byte, short, int, long) puede ser asignado pero cuando el valor exceda long me diga que no cabe en ninguno, sin embargo la salida tiene que mostrar el valor ingresado, ya intente directamente con una variable tipo long pero la tengo que usar en el catch, trate cambiando el long por un double y luego haciendo el cast en el bloque try pero me devuelve el valor maximo que cabe en el long
`

import java.util.*;

public class DatosPrimitivos {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int iterator = sc.nextInt();
    for (int i = 0; i < iterator; i++) {
        double numero = sc.nextDouble();
        try {
            long prueba = (long)numero;
            dataTypes(prueba);
        } catch (ArithmeticException e) {
            System.out.println(numero + " can be fitted anywhere.");
        }

    }
    sc.close();
}

public static void dataTypes(Long numero) {
    String b = "byte", s = "short", i = "int", l = "long";
    if (numero >= -128 && numero <= 127) {
        System.out.println(numero + " can be fitted in:");
        System.out.println("*" + b + "\n*" + s + "\n*" + i + "\n*" + l);
    } else if (numero >= -32768 && numero <= 32767) {
        System.out.println(numero + " can be fitted in:");
        System.out.println("*" + s + "\n*" + i + "\n*" + l);
    } else if (numero >= -2147483648 && numero <= 2147483647) {
        System.out.println(numero + " can be fitted in:");
        System.out.println("*" + i + "\n*" + l);
    } else {
        System.out.println(numero + " can be fitted in:");
        System.out.println("*" + l);
    }
}
```

}
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para responder directamente al título de la pregunta: **No puedes** convertir un valor a un tipo de variable entera dónde el número excede la capacidad del tipo. Por eso mismo se eleva una excepción y no se asigna ningún valor a dicha variable.

La buena noticia es que no tienes que hacer conversiones de tipo para lograr lo que quieres.

Puedes valerte de los métodos [`hasNextXXX`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextByte--) de la clase `Scanner` para determinar si el valor ingresado por el usuario puede interpretarse como alguno de los tipos que quieres soportar: `hasNextByte()`, `hasNextLong()`, etc.

Una vez `haxNextXXX()` te devuelve verdadero, puedes utilizar con seguridad el método `nextXXX` para obtener la entrada en una variable del tipo apropiado.

Luego, para realizar la *validación* es de ir en orden por esos tipos del menor al mayor, de manera similar a cómo lo haces ya en tu código, y si llegas al final, puedes leer el valor ingresado como un `String`, para poder imprimir el mensaje correspondiente, incluyendo el valor, pues sea lo que sea que esté allí, no puede ser almacenado en ninguno de los tipos.

Te dejo un ejemplo que lo hace:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.print("# of integers to enter: ");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int iterator = sc.nextInt();
    for (int i = 0; i < iterator; i++) {
        System.out.print("\nInteger number: ");
        try {
            if (sc.hasNextByte()) {
                byte num = sc.nextByte();
                System.out.println(num + " can be fitted in byte, short, int, long");
            } else if (sc.hasNextShort()) {
                short num = sc.nextShort();
                System.out.println(num + " can be fitted in short, int, long");
            } else if (sc.hasNextInt()) {
                int num = sc.nextInt();
                System.out.println(num + " can be fitted in int, long");
            } else if (sc.hasNextLong()) {
                long num = sc.nextLong();
                System.out.println(num + " can be fitted in long");
            } else {
                String valor = sc.next();
                System.out.println(valor + " cannot be stored as byte, short, int or long value");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getClass().getName() + "\n" + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    sc.close();
    System.out.println("\nProgam end!");
}
```